# CURL en codeigniter no tiene errores pero devuelve un objeto vacío como respuesta

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap, curl

Estoy haciendo un servicio en Codeigniter que consume un Soap WebService a través de CURL, ya les mostraré el código, pero primero el problema, resulta que al mandar el request al SOAP en un principio llegaba null como respuesta, luego me di cuenta de que tenía problemas con la comprobación de certificados SSL, lo resolví desbloqueando todo lo que tenía relación con SSL en el archivo php.ini, ya que con ese problema resuelto, no hubo más errores en el request, pero la respuesta del servicio fue un objeto(JSON) vació. A continuación les mostraré el código para que vean como esta estructurado el servicio, como se construyo el request y la llamada al SOAP. Ojalas puedan orientarme y decirme que puede faltar o que pude haber hecho mal para que llegue una respuesta vacía.

```
$soapUrl         = "https://ws.aminerals.cl:8022/RMES/ProxyServices/db_RMES_JIGSAW?wsdl"; // asmx URL of WSDL
$soapUser        = "userdev";                                                             //  username
$soapPassword    = "userdev123";                                                          // password
$xml_post_string = '
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                xmlns:sp="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/jmineops/dbo/SP_DETALLE_TIEMPOS_ESTADOS/">
                <soapenv:Header/>  
                <soapenv:Body>
                   <sp:InputParameters>
                    <sp:FECHA_DESDE>20180103</sp:FECHA_DESDE>
                    <sp:FECHA_HASTA>20180104</sp:FECHA_HASTA>
                    <sp:EQUIPO>B03</sp:EQUIPO>
                   </sp:InputParameters>
                 </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: ",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
);
$url     = $soapUrl;
$ch      = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser . ":" . $soapPassword);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    curl_close($ch);

    // converting
    $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>", "", $response);
    $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>", "", $response1);

    // convertingc to XML
    $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
    // user $parser to get your data out of XML response and to display it.
    var_dump($parser);
}
```

Si alguno ve algo que yo no haya visto que pueda estar mal, ayúdeme por favor.

Answer (score 0):

para realizar peticiones SOAP puedes utilizar una librería como [NuSOAP](https://github.com/pwnlabs/nusoap).

Ejemplo de uso (sin probar):

```php
$client = new nusoap_client("https://ws.aminerals.cl:8022/RMES/ProxyServices/db_RMES_JIGSAW?wsdl", 'wsdl');
$client->soap_defencoding = config_item('charset');
$client->decode_utf8 = FALSE;
$client->setCredentials("userdev", "userdev123");
$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    return new Exception("{$error}");
}

$result = $client->call('db_RMES_JIGSAW', $xml_post_string); // Operación y parámetros
if ($client->fault) {
    log_message('ERROR', json_encode($result));

    return false;
}

return is_array($result) ? $result : json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) me sirvio mucho tu respuesta. Disculpa haber demorado en agredecerte la ayuda, estuve algo desconectado de todo un tiempo. :D